# php download a txt file in a response headers

Tags: php, download

I try to write a php script to automatically download some file from a website, i use `get_file_content`  all the response haedaers from that site, but i dont know to to save it as a file. The response header as shown as the screen image. if i access that url in browser the file will save into my computer but i cant use php script to save it.

is that possible to do it with script?

#### header image

[image]

thanks for helping me. i did not describe my problem very well, i want to save the attachment in that hearder, like in my header example `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=savedrecs.txt`, i want to save that file into my computer

Comment: http://php.net/file_put_contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By making use of `$http_response_header` as the content and `file_put_contents` as the function for writing.

```
<?php
file_get_contents('http://www.stackoverflow.com'); //<--- Pass your website here
file_put_contents('test.txt',implode(PHP_EOL,$http_response_header)); //<--- Passing the $http_response_header as the text
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: http://stackoverflow.com/
Date: Wed, 26 Feb 2014 09:25:37 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 148
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=27
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Wed, 26 Feb 2014 09:26:05 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 26 Feb 2014 09:25:05 GMT
Vary: *
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Wed, 26 Feb 2014 09:25:38 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 212557
```

Comment: thanks for helping me. i did not describe my problem very well, i want to save the attachment in that hearder, like in my header example `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=savedrecs.txt`, i want to save that file into my computer